# How to display full width block without toolbar?

Tags: editor, block-editor

I'm trying to create a full width blocks for the new Gutenberg editor, however I don't want to give to option to toggle the block alignment (eg: like the **Cover** block does) just make it full width all the time.

I managed to add support for this with the `supports` flag in my block:

```
supports: {
    align: ['full']
}

attributes: {
    align: {
        type: 'string',
        default: 'full'
    }
}
```

This shows the block in the admin area as full width by default but it also displays the Block Alignment Toolbar at the top so it can be toggled on/off:

[image: gif]

Is there a way to set the block alignment without displaying the toolbar?

Comment: This was answered over here. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325724/style-new-block-editor-alignfull-class-without-scrollbars-or-overflow ... It's the only way I've seen to make this work without scroll bars in Windows / Linux systems that have proper vertical scrollbars (which are what cause the horizontal scrollbar).